# How do I prove $A(B+C) = AB+AC$ in Boolean expression?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I need help to prove that $A(B+C) = AB + AC$ in Boolean. It’s been years since I did this and a friend asked for help. I tried but I can’t seem to get it right. Can someone explain how to prove it using Boolean? I was told that my [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JtlT.jpg) does not show clearly that it's true.

[image]

Comment: What do you think is wrong in the picture?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a diagram with $\{A,B,C\}$ and assign values 0 or 1 to each element in the diagram and check when the the statement $A(B + C)$ is true.

For example if $A = 1$, $B=1$ and $C = 0$, which is equivalent to $AB$, $A(B+C)$ is true.

Edit : It is important to know that $0 + 1 = 1 + 0 = 1 + 1 = 1$  ; $0 + 0 = 0$
;$1*1 = 1$ ;$0 = 0*1=1*0=0*0$

Comment: I did this earlier but I didn't put it in as my working.... which was required.. zzz thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is just an straight-forward instance of Distribution:

**Distribution**

$P(Q+R)=PQ+PR$

$P+QR=(P+Q)(P+R)$

But, if you need to prove Distribution itself, you can use a truth-table:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c}
A&B&C&A(B+C)&AB+AC\\
\hline
T&T&T&T&T\\
T&T&F&T&T\\
T&F&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&F&F\\
F&T&T&F&F\\
F&T&F&F&F\\
F&F&T&F&F\\
F&F&F&F&F\\
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you! This was what the teacher wanted since there's a clear comparison instead of just the equations.. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @lmao Glad I could help :)